# How to implement a dynamic Bootstrap 4 accordion, using Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 (I have jQuery installed also) to create an accordion along with Vue.js

I have used the **v-for** directive on the card that I want to replicate for each item in a json file. However the accordion stops working as the data-target and id is the same. I have tried using v-bind (***:data-target="'#collapse'+index"***) as you will see in my example below, but I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Here is part of the code:

```
<div class="card" v-for="(faq, index) in filteredfaqs">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button
            class="btn btn-link"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            :data-target="'#collapse'+index"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseOne"
          >{{ faq.title}}</button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div
        id="'#collapse'+index"
        class="collapse show"
        aria-labelledby="headingOne"
        data-parent="#accordion"
      >
        <div class="card-body">{{ faq.body | snippet }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: did u try use BootstrapVue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the `id` with a static value which is `'#collapse'+index` instead it should be bidden dynamically and without the `#` symbol:

```html
<div v-bind:id="'collapse'+index"
      class="collapse show"
      aria-labelledby="headingOne" 
      data-parent="#accordion"
></div>
```

Here is a Demo : [codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/dybOdKQ)